# Symfony2 locale detection: not considering _locale in session

Tags: symfony, localization, translation, locale

I'm trying to implement a LocaleListener that detects user's preferred language (considering Accept-Language header) and stores it in session to avoid checking it every request. I've developed the code below to accomplish this:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
        return;
    }

    $preferredLocale = $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->availableLocales);

    if ($this->container->has('session')) {
        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        if (!$session->has('_locale')) {
            $session->set('_locale', $preferredLocale);
        }
    } else {
        $request->setLocale($preferredLocale);
    }
}
```

The code is working, the preferred language is being stored in session, but symfony isn't considering the locale stored in session to translate strings. In my case, my preferred language was 'pt_BR' and when I escape:

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

symfony is escaping 'en'. Shouldn't symfony be considering the value stored in session('_locale') to define request locale? Is this a correct behavior? How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a working language listener. the second method is to change the language to the users preferences, which the user chooses. You can omit this method, if your user haven't the facility to define their language.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class LanguageListener
{
    private $session;

    public function setSession(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * kernel.request event. If a guest user doesn't have an opened session, locale is equal to
     * "undefined" as configured by default in parameters.ini. If so, set as a locale the user's
     * preferred language.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if ('undefined' == $request->getLocale()) {
            if ($locale = $request->getSession()->get('_locale')) {
                $request->setLocale($locale);
            } else {
                $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * security.interactive_login event. If a user chose a language in preferences, it would be set,
     * if not, a locale that was set by setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser remains.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if ($lang = $user->getLanguage()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $lang);
        }
    }
}
```

in your services.yml:

```
services:
    acme.language.interactive_login_listener:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LanguageListener
        calls:
            - [ setSession, [@session] ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }

    acme.language.kernel_request_listener:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LanguageListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser }
```

Oh, and you have to define an undefined fallback_language in config.yml to get it work.

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "undefined" }
    default_locale:  "en"
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pazi. I have two questions about your snippet: 1) is it a good ideia to set the locale in every request? I've tried to avoid this storing locale in session. 2) Where did you set your locale in session? What do your method $user->getLanguage() returns?

Comment: In my project it's no problem. I got this snippet also from another source, but I don't know the url anymore.. May you can modify it to use only the `_locale` in the session. In the past as i introduced this, it hadn't worked. `$user->getLanguage()` is simple a language field in my user entity, 'cause my users can decide in what language to use the webapplication, independently from the browsers locale.

Answer (score 7):

As of symfony 2.1, the locale is not stored in the session, but in the request. What you can do to solve it:

- restore the old way of saving the locale. You can read how to do this in the [upgrade file](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#simulate-old-behavior)
- edit the LocaleListener to store the locale in the request:

  ```
  if (!$request->attributes->has('locale')) {
      $request->setLocale(...);
  }
  ```

Comment: The [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/translation.html#handling-the-user-s-locale) says that its also possible to store locale in session. Isn't it automatic? Or a bug should be reported? "It is also possible to store the locale in the session instead of on a per request basis. If you do this, each subsequent request will have this locale."

Comment: @hugomn please note this cite: "If you do this, **each subsequent request will have this locale.**" And we aren't talking about sub request, aren't we? So it will not work.

Comment: I didn't get it. So it means that symfony doesn't consider the key _locale in session for subsequent requests?

Comment: The locale is stored in the request and not in the session. If you store it in the session, that locale will be used for subrequests and not for the main request.

Comment: There is a difference between "subsequent requests" and "subrequests". I think there is something wrong either in Symfony or the documentation, because if I set the locale in the session, I expect every request in this session to have that locale (not only subrequests).