# Symfony2 Set _locale in home page base on browser's configuration

Tags: symfony, localization, translation

My local works everywhere on my website but I cant tell the application the set the proper local on the root of the application.

### For exemple :

If my website is http://mycompany.com I want that, when I enter this address the application guess what is my local and set it at the end of the url 
http://mycompany.com/en if the local exist on my application. Here `en` or `fr` and if not the default `en`

For now when i go to home page I always get english version but my browser is set in french

### routing.yml :

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:landing, _locale: en }
    requirements:
        _locale: en|fr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of many other questions related to locale and symfony2 I finally get want I want ! I guess it is not the perfect answer but at least it works !

My landing action is defined in my routing as `_welcome` route. It is this action that is loaded when I go to the url's root.

```
     /**
     * @Route("/landing")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function landingAction() {

        $localeAvailable = array('en', 'fr');
        //user language
        $localeUser = substr($this->getRequest()->getPreferredLanguage(), 0, 2);
        //application language
        $localeApp = $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_locale');

        //Redirect to the good locale page 
        //only if the locale user is on our manager locale and it is not the current locale of the application
        if(in_array($localeUser, $localeAvailable) && $localeApp!=$localeUser){
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("_welcome", array('_locale' => $localeUser)));
        }

        return array();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350846/symfony2-locale-detection-not-considering-locale-in-session/16356280#16356280) asked a few days ago and take a look at the first method in the language listener. It does exactly what you need. And take care of the right settings in config.yml

Comment: Thx for your help, I red this question before, that was part of the answer ! and i upvoted it