# SetLocale() for all pages with Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony-2.2

I'm trying to make multi languages site with symfony 2, the question now is how to make `$request->setLocale()` applicable on all pages or methods.For the moment I needed in every method to call `$request->setLocale($newlanguage);`

```
public function methodAAction()
{
    ...
    $request->setLocale($new_language);
    return $this->render('x');
}

public function methodBAction()
{
     ...
    $request->setLocale($new_language);
    return $this->render('y');
}
```

Is there any way to make it Global , I mean to call it only one time for all pages

Comment: For the same class you can move the call in `__construct()` ; otherwise you can create an event listener and change the locale based on session, request parameter, or whatever.

Comment: I'm nowbie, can u be more explicit pls

Comment: To change it for all the methods within a class, create a constructor and make the call to change the locale from there: `public function __construct() { $request->setLocale($new_language); }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a listener which sets the locale for every request. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350846/symfony2-locale-detection-not-considering-locale-in-session/16356280#16356280) on another question for some good code. Only the `setLocaleForUnauthenticatedUser` is necessary for your problem.

Comment: I did it like u tell @Pazi but getlocale() in the listener is evrytime 'en' , he dont recognize the 'undefined', Why? otherwise if i write only setlocal(...) evrthing work good but if i leave the conditions nothing work.what was my mistake here?

Comment: Have you set the fallback in the config.yml? And which symfony version do you use? I've tested them only til the latest 2.2 version.

Comment: yes i did evryhing in the config.yml and i use Symfony 2.2.1 version.is there any other possibility to change this condition bc without it the code works good

Comment: Did you remove every `$request->setLocale($new_language);` line in the controllers?

Comment: Hmm, confusing. It works for me. Don't know where the error is. Is anything in the logs?

Comment: nothing special, should i may be do something in my controller? or no

Comment: No, only the three files. The listener class, the service definition in services.yml and the two changes in config.yml. Then it should work.

Comment: Now for example when i change default_locale : 'undefined' in my config , it works good. is there something wrong?