# How to store session in language var in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

How to store session in language var ?
My `parameters.ini` sets default local

```
locale = en
```

My `config.yml` sets default locale

```
translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

And I have changed language in language controller

```
public function languageAction(Request $request)
{

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $request->setLocale('fr_FR');


        // BOTH CODE TRY IT ABOVE AND BELLOW BUT NOT RUN ANY ONE


        $session = $this->get('session');
        $session->set('locale', 'fr_FR');


}
```

I have set fr_FR language in session "locale", and I have echo "Locale" other  Controller   so get value "en" inserted of "fr_FR"

Following way I have echo locale value

```
class galleryController extends Dashboard
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
    echo $request->getLocale(); 

    **or**

    $session = $this->get('session');
        echo $session->get('locale');

    }
}
```

How to set session in  setLocale and  getLocale  in "'fr_FR' lang

Comment: Does `$this->get('session')->isStarted()` return true?

Comment: i want  following    ans  but how 
 echo $request->getLocale(); 

ans =   "'en' 
but i want  "'fr_FR'  

"'fr_FR'  instead of "en"

Comment: i understand what your problem is ... can't help you if you don't answer my question :)

Comment: return true 

ANS :   1

:)

Comment: $this->get('session')->isStarted()     yes return true  and ans is 1

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350846/symfony2-locale-detection-not-considering-locale-in-session) should probably help you out.